# Is using Try[Unit] the proper way?

Tags: scala, error-handling, scala-2.10

I recently came across the concept of `Try`/`Success`/`Failure`, and I am wondering how to use it for a method that has the return type `Unit`. Is using `Try[Unit]` the correct way? Maybe I am too influenced from my Java background, but is it a good idea to force the caller to deal with the problem?

Comment: If the method has no meaningful return type (except for possibly generating a failure), why not `Option[MyException]` with `None` being the default case, and `Some(exception)` being the result in case of errors?

Comment: Yes, `Try[Unit]` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Dirk Because you should avoid special cases. If you have one method returning `Try[String]` and another method taking `String` and returning `Option[Exception]`, they are harder to use together than if the second method returns `Try[Unit]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Try[Unit]` is normal. For example, if you persist the entity, you can use:

```
try { 
    em.persist(entity)
} catch{
  case ex:PersistenceException =>
  handle(ex)
}
```

or just

```
Try(em.persist(entity)) match {
  case Success(_) => 
  case Failure(ex) => handle(ex)
}
```

Comment: Oh, I did not know I can also use a catch at this point. Thanks.