# Why am I getting an (inconsistent) compiler error when using a for comprehension with a result of Try[Unit]?

Tags: scala, output, mutable

A common pattern I have in my code base is to define methods with `Try[Unit]` to indicate the method is doing something (like writing a transaction long to a SaaS REST endpoint) where there is no interesting return result and I want to capture any and emit any errors encountered to `stdout`. I have read on another [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898507/is-using-tryunit-the-propper-way) this is [entirely acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23908583/501113) (also see 2nd comment on the question).

I am **specifically and explicitly avoiding actually throwing and catching an exception** which is an extraordinarily expensive activity on most JVM implementations.  This means any answer which uses the `Try()` idiom won't help resolve my issue.

I have the following code (vastly simplified from my real life scenario):

```
def someMethod(transactionToLog: String): Try[Unit] = {
  val result =
    for {
      _ <- callToSomeMethodReturningATryInstance
    } yield Unit
  result match {
    case Success(_)
      //Unit
    case Failure(e) ->
      println(s"oopsie - ${e.getMessage}")
  }
  result
}
```

Sometimes this code compiles just fine. Sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't, it gives me the following compilation error:

```
Error:(row, col) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.util.Try[Unit.type]
 required: scala.util.Try[Unit]
    result
    ^
```

Sometimes the IntelliJ syntax highlighter shows the code as fine. Other times [it shows an error](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9110) (roughly the same as the one above). And sometimes I get the compiler error but not a highligher error. And other times it compiles fine and I get only a highlighter error. And thus far, I am having a difficult time finding a perfect "example" to capture the compiler error.

I attempted to "cure" the issue by adding `.asInstanceOf[Unit]` to the result of the `for` comprehension. That got it past the compiler. However, now I am getting a runtime exception of `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Unit$ cannot be cast to scala.runtime.BoxedUnit`. Naturally, this is infinitely worse than the original compilation error.

So, two questions:

1. Assuming `Try[Unit]` isn't valid, what is the Scala idiomatic (or even just preferred) way to specify a `Try` which returns no useful `Success` result?
2. Assuming `Try[Unit]` is valid, how do I get past the compilation error (described above)?

---

**SIDENOTE:**
I must have hit this problem a year ago and didn't remember the details. I created the solution below which I have all over my code bases. However, recently I started using `Future[Unit]` in a number of places. And when I first tried `Try[Unit]`, it appeared to work. However, the number of times it is now causing both compilation and [IDE highlighting issues](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9110) has grown quite a bit. So, I want to make a final decision about how to proceed which is consistent with whatever exists (or is even emerging) and is Scala idiomatic.

```
package org.scalaolio.util

/** This package object serves to ease Scala interactions with mutating
 *  methods.
 */
package object Try_ {
  /** Placeholder type for when a mutator method does not intend to
   *  return anything with a Success, but needs to be able to return a
   *  Failure with an unthrown Exception.
   */
  sealed case class CompletedNoException private[Try_] ()

  /** Placeholder instance for when a mutator method needs to indicate
   *  success via Success(completedNoExceptionSingleton)
   */
  val completedNoExceptionSingleton = new CompletedNoException()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `yield Unit` with `yield ()`.

`Unit` is a type - `()` is a value (and the only possible value) of type `Unit`.

That is why `for { _ <- expr } yield Unit` results in a `Try[Unit.type]`, just as `yield String` would result in a `Try[String.type]`.

Comment: Fantastic! That is exactly what I was missing. Tysvm!